# Find object from a collection according to created date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection ticket_masters,which contain createdAt field and it store the date and time .

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e78f2ddc0e09128e81db47a",
        "NAME": "Jasin",
        "PHONE": "2252545414",
        "MAIL": "sdsdm@m.com",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-23T17:33:17.470Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-03-23T17:33:17.470Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Now i want find records according to createAt field from the user collection. Already tried with the following code snippet.

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find({
    "createdAt" : '2020-03-17T18:30:00.237+00:00'
    })
```

Output :

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms
```

But zero records found as per the above code snippet.Kindly help me to resolve issues
Thank you

Comment: Hi there! Do you have a schema for `ticket_masters` somewhere? If yes, please share. Also, how do you go about inserting the `ticket_masters` into the DB? Lastly, are you certain that there is a document in the DB with that particular "createdAt" value in the DB?

Comment: yes i have schema for ticket_master .CreateAt field  automatically generated by the mongoDB

Comment: Please share that schema. Also, where are you executing the `db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find` query, withing your application code or in the mongo CLI?

Comment: Robo 3T  is used for executing the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying the Date type.

The `$eq` operator matches documents where the value of a field equals the specified value.

```
// Date and time

db.getCollection('ticket_masters').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
           "createdAt": {$eq: new Date('2020-03-17T18:30:00.237+00:00')}
        }
    },
])

OR 

// Only Date

db.getCollection('ticket_masters').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
           "createdAt": {"$gte": new Date("2020-03-17"), $lt : new Date("2020-03-18") }
        }
    },
])
```

> The dates you saved were new Date(), which includes the time components. To query those times you need to create a date range that includes all moments in a day

Using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

**Example:**

```
// start today
var start = moment().startOf('day');
// end today
var end = moment(today).endOf('day');

{ createdAt: { '$gte': start, '$lte': end }
```

`$gt` Matches values that are greater than a specified value.

`$lt` Matches values that are less than a specified value.

For more information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Comment: Thank you.It's working but it contain both date and time.i just looking for date only and passing value as dd:mm:yyyy format,which doesn't contain time

Comment: @SufailKalathil I have updated the answer. The dates you saved were new Date(), which includes the time components. To query those times you need to create a date range that includes all moments in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find({
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-17T18:30:00.237+00:00")
})
```

or you can try this.

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "createdAt":ISODate("2020-03-17T18:30:00.237+00:00")
        }
    },
])
```